# Using System.Random.Mersenne.Pure64 to generate a random Float in the range [0,1]

Tags: haskell, random, mersenne-twister

I do not want to use System.Random because it is significantly slower and I need to generate millions of random floats. I also cannot use System.Random.MWC because it is not pure.

I made an attempt at writing this myself but my solution does not generate a uniform range, all the values are very close to 0.

```
randomRMSP :: (Float,Float) -> PureMT -> (Float,PureMT)                   
randomRMSP (lo,hi) rng =
    let (f,rng') = first double2Float (randomDouble rng)
    in (lo + f / (maxFloat + 1) * (hi - lo + 1),rng')

maxRealFloat :: RealFloat a => a -> a                                           
maxRealFloat a = encodeFloat m n where                                          
    b = floatRadix a                                                            
    e = floatDigits a                                                           
    (_, e') = floatRange a                                                      
    m = b ^ e - 1                                                               
    n = e' - e
```

I'm pretty sure the maxRealFloat function is correct because it returns the [correct values for Floats and Doubles according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realized I was making a very silly mistake. 
The function randomDouble in System.Random.Mersenne.Pure64 returns a double already in the range [0,1] (which the [documentation does not mention at all](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mersenne-random-pure64-0.2.0.4/docs/System-Random-Mersenne-Pure64.html)) and consquently all my numbers were very small because I was dividing them by the max double.